# Проблема с добавлением обновлённого списка в Treeview

Tags: python, list, tkinter, treeview, value

Есть один вопрос, который я не могу решить. Вроде всё правильно: допустим есть пустой список:

```py
books = []
```

Есть функция, которая при исполнении добавляет в данный список новые значения из переменной в которую они попадают:

```py
def add():
    books.append(new_list)
```

И есть `TreeView` который отображает таблицу, а значения он берёт по канону:

```py
for value in books:
    tree_books.insert("", END, values=value)
```

Проблема в том, что функция работает - я вижу, что программа запомнила новые значения в списке - она добавила их, но вот таблица всё равно пустая.
Таблица создана правильно: при занесении данных непосредственно в переменную `books` с самого начала выдаёт в таблице всё, что в ней указано. Однако новые данные, которые она получает в ходе программы таблица отображать отказывается.
Я даже пробовал в функции прописывать `global`, но толку никакого...
Что не так, подскажите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужно этот цикл заполнения таблицы

```py
for value in books:
    tree_books.insert("", END, values=value)
```

выполнять каждый раз, когда вы обновляете список (например, в функции `add`).

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы - если цикл ввожу в саму функцию он делает обновление! Спасибо огромное. Можно уточнение, а нельзя ли обойти подобный момент?

Comment: Что значит "обойти"? Не обновлять каждый раз?

Comment: Да, не прописывать цикл в функцию. Я просто хочу понимать все возможности, чтобы быть лучше после решения таких проблем =)

Comment: Как не обновлять её каждый раз я, честно говоря, не знаю...